# counter-example for quotient of artinian and noetherian modules

Tags: modules, examples-counterexamples, noetherian, artinian

Suppose I have an $R$-module $P$ and let $M, N\in P$ be submodules. Furthermore, suppose that both $M$ and $N$ are artinian and noetherian. Is it always true that the quotient $P/M\cap N$ is also artinian and noetherian?

I definitely think it is not always true, but I failed to come up with a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-Artinian, non-Noetherian module containing two distinct simple submodules would work, because then $P/(M\cap N)\cong P$.

This suggests $R=F$ for a field $F$, and choose $P$ to be an infinite dimensional $F$ vector space, and $M\neq N$ any two distinct 1-dimensional subspaces of $P$.

Comment: Thanks. Now that I come to think about it, requesting $P/ M\cap N$ is artinian and noetherian must mean that $P$ should be noetherian and artinian because also $M\cap N$ is artinian and noetherian.

Comment: @User666x True.